# Count of the number of nodes tagged with a particular status

Tags: views, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type called promise whose node can be tagged with a status: not started, in progress, achieved, broken.

I wish to show a count for each of the above statuses in a view block. So say there are 100 promises, I want it to show the following.

- 90 of 100 promises are not started
- 2 of 100 promises are in progress
- 3 of 100 promises are achieved
- 5 of 100 promises are broken

How can I go about this? I know how to count a taxonomy term and show it has 2, 3 or 18 nodes tagged against it, but how to show out of 100?

Comment: What do you think is the difference between 2, 3 or 18 nodes against 100?

Comment: The other nodes that are not part of that equation, so 2 nodes, it would be the other 3 statuses added together. I understand that, but not how to do it in views.

Answer (score 1):

To do this without code, I think you'd need a view for each category and then in the footer or header, choose "Global: Results summary" and build your message there using the tokens. I saw you post about colours elsewhere so if you have a separate block for each, you can then theme each one as you wish.

If you set the view to "Display All Items" and then add css `.viewname .view-content {display:none;}` or a custom module to hide the results, it should work nicely.

You could then use some caching to minimize the performance hit.